# Do SEO-friendly URLs really affect a page's ranking?

Tags: seo, friendly-url

SEO-friendly URLs are all the rage these days. But do they actually have a meaningful impact on a page's ranking in Google and other search engines? If so, why? If not, why not?

(Note that I would absolutely agree that SEO-friendly URLs are nicer to use for human beings. My question is whether they actually make a difference to the ranking algorithms.)

**Update:** As it turns out, the Google post that endorphine points to [here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html) has caused tremendous confusion in the SEO community. For a sampling of the discussion, see [here](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls-the-best-practice-for-seo-is-still-clear), [here](http://sphinn.com/story/74404), and [here](http://searchengineland.com/google-says-dont-rewrite-dynamic-urls-to-static-urls-14795). Part of the problem is that the Google post is addressing the worst case where URL rewriting is done poorly and so you'd be better off sticking with a dynamic URL rather than a mangled static "SEO-friendly" URL.

There's no question dynamic URLs can be crawled by Google and can achieve high rankings. Maybe it would be easier to reframe the question more concretely: given 2 otherwise equivalent pages, which will rank higher for the search "do seo friendly urls really affect page ranking"?

A) [Do SEO-friendly URLs really affect a page's ranking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505793/do-seo-friendly-urls-really-affect-a-pages-ranking)

or

B) http://stackoverflow.com?question=505793 (a fake URL for comparison only)

Comment: of course they are. After all, it's why they got the name SEO-friendly URLs. :)

Comment: This question is not really programming related.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this type of topic is no longer acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 20):

I will let google answer to your question:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html

In the article:

> Which can Googlebot read better,
>   static or dynamic URLs? [...]While
>   static URLs might have a slight
>   advantage in terms of clickthrough
>   rates because users can easily read
>   the urls, the decision to use
>   database-driven websites does not
>   imply a significant disadvantage in
>   terms of indexing and ranking.
>   Providing search engines with dynamic
>   URLs should be favored over hiding
>   parameters to make them look static

Comment: @endorphine - that's an interesting article, and it matches my own experience with dynamic URLs. But it doesn't answer the question. Google's statement in that post is that you shouldn't rewrite URLs because you might mess them up, and thus confuse Google. Which doesn't address the SEO angle.

Comment: Well, google says there is no real difference in page-ranking except that users can easily read the url and it may help you site getting more visits and getting a better page-rank.

Comment: I would argue that the higher click through rates get counted (in part) towards rankings. Also remember that Google highlights keywords in the SERPS including keywords found in the url.

Answer (score 16):

Even if search engines didn't give your pages a better rank, you should still do it for the users. Any benefit for SEO is just icing on your site.

SEOmoz had an article with suggestions for [URL best practices](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/11-best-practices-for-urls) along with reasons why each is helpful for usability or search engines.

Comment: From the article: "...our search traffic jumps more than 20% once we switch to the new, friendlier URLs."

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this question is readily answerable except by anecdotal evidence, since no two pages are "otherwise equivalent" enough to measure in the sense you're asking.  Beyond a Google search engineer emerging and divulging the answer, if one exists that's limited to only this property, you're unlikely to get a definitive answer; more likely, you'll get a long stream of most-likelies.

But I do like the suggestion that descriptive URLs improve the user experience; I think that's true with respect to short URLs, definitely (e.g., "/help", or "/ask", etc.).  One just has to decide how valuable that benefit is to the project, when weighed against the cost of creating such URL schemes, which can sometimes be pricey; I've had a couple of clients who've spent thousands on exactly this effort, with no measurable effect in search ranking whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword frequency and pagerank are really the two main factors in SEO.

It follows, then, that including keywords in your URLs is desirable.

e.g. http://my_site.com/article/keyword is better than http://mysite.com/article/42

Answer (score 1):

All else being equal, both pages will achieve the same pagerank. Pagerank is determined by how many people link to you and what their page rank is. So, it does not affect your pagerank.

But it does affect how high you will end up in the search results. In the search index, not only page rank but also keyword relevance matters. If you have the keywords in your url and someone searches for them, then your page will be more relevant and be higher in the search results. Also, when people link to you then the keyword-rich URLs they use to link to you will also improve your relevance.

Don't stare yourself blind at pagerank. It doesn't matter that much. What matters is that you get found by people. Pagerank is only a small (and ever decreasing) part of that.