# Why use page title in URL?

Tags: seo, search-engine, friendly-url

> Why some sites, most blogs, use title
>   of the post in the url? As in:
>
> > http://www.geek.com.br/blogs/832697632/posts/9360-uni-o-europ-ia-pretende-apoiar-conex-o-universal-para-celulares
>
> Will this improve google indexing?

**EDIT: this is a duplicate of [Why do some websites add “Slugs” to the end of URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427/why-do-some-websites-add-slugs-to-the-end-of-urls)**

Comment: dupe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505793/do-seo-friendly-urls-really-affect-a-pages-ranking

Comment: More closely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47427/why-do-some-websites-add-slugs-to-the-end-of-urls, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Also makes it very human readable. You can see a link and know what the content is going to be like. Whereas numbers mean nothing.

Answer (score 1):

According to Robin, not only _human_readable, but **search engine** readable

It's very good to use page titles in your url, because Google, Yahoo etc. use this as a keyword.

Comment: No, they don't. Read the link in the comment I posted above.

Comment: They do, which is why it uses dashes instead of underscores since Google only uses a dash as a word delimiter.